# Spring Boot Application can't connect to a local SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I'm creating a spring boot application, but I'm not able to connect it to a local sql server.

Here's my POM file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=myDB

spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

The SQL Server is running on the port 1433 (TCP enabled), but when i run the application i got the following error:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

which i don't know how to solve.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding encrypt=false to datasource url might fix the problem.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-drive-10